# gulp : multiple libs for one app

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to build multiple libs for a single application using gulp.

I have this directory structure

```
dist/ # expected result
  lib1.js 
  lib2.js
src/
  libs/
    lib1/
      ... # js files for lib1
    lib2/
      ... # js files for lib2
  wrap/ # wrappers, one per lib
    lib1.js
    lib2.js
```

And I wrote this gulp task, using through2 :

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
  var dn = 'azerty'; // whatever 

  return  gulp.src('src/libs/**/*.js')
   .pipe(through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
      // for extracting a lib's dirname
      var str = path.dirname(file.path),
        parts = str.split('/'),
        rev = parts.reverse();

      dn = rev[0];
      util.log(dn); // al is ok here...
      cb();
    }))
    .pipe(concat(dn + '.js'))
    .pipe(wrap({ src : 'src/wrap/' + dn + '.js'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

But it doesn't work properly, the value of 'dn' variable seems to be lost at the concat point, this is very strange because 'dn' is a global variable relatively to the task :*

How to work around this ? By using gulp-foreach or something other ?

Regards.

EDIT : this is sadly the same with gulp-foreach... someone has an idea to solve this  ?